# High degree polynomial plotting with Tikz/pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am new to tikz/pgfplots...so sorry if my question has been asked...

I am trying to plot the tanh function using pgplots, then add a set of N points and plot the (n-1) degree polynomial passing through the points...

Here is what I have done so far:

The tanh should vary between -1 and 1 but when I try to plot a high degree polynomial, the y axis is rescaled... If I try to reduce the domain value I get an error message from pdflatex...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       clip=true,
       width = 10cm, height= 8cm,
       xlabel = {$x$},
       ylabel = {$f(x)$},
       ymin=-2, ymax=2, xmin=-10, xmax=10]
       \addplot[domain=-10:10,smooth] gnuplot[id=tanh]{tanh(x)};
       \foreach \data in {-3,-2,-1,0,1, 2, 3}{
          \addplot[only marks, black] coordinates {(\data, {tanh(\data)})};
        }
       \addplot[domain=-10:10, samples=25, smooth] gnuplot[id=poly]{(x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Any idea will be helpful!

I am trying to reproduce that figure:

tanh fitted with a degree 14 lagrangian polynomial...

[image]

And Here is my updated code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width = 10cm, height= 8cm,
      xlabel = {$x$},
      ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    ]
    \addplot[smooth] gnuplot[id=tanh]{tanh(x)};
    \addplot[only marks, samples at={-10,-8.57,...,10}]{tanh(x)};
    \addplot[samples=25, smooth, red, thick] gnuplot[id=poly]
            {(0.000000000138483*x^13-0.000000039937808*x^11+0.000004411606097*x^9-0.000237588565393*x^7+
            0.006610739962583*x^5-0.094756895881911*x^3+0.791753916669373*x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Mathematical remark: You try to plot a polynom of degree 7 in a y - range vom -10^7 to 10^7, whereas `tanh` is a restricted function, i.e. only in the -1 and 1, what do you expect then? ;-). I.e. your domain is ways too large!!!!

Comment: The Taylor expansion of tanh is `x-1/3 x^3 + 2/15 x^5....`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.

Comment: Two general comments: You don't need to use `gnuplot` for this particular plot, PGFPlots can handle this natively; and instead of the `\foreach` construct, you can simply use  `\addplot[only marks,  samples at={-3,-2,...,3}] {tanh(x)};` to generate the dots.

Comment: To get your second example to work: Set `domain=-10:10, samples=55` in the `axis` options. Again, you can remove `gnuplot[id=poly]`, PGFPlots can plot this directly.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you want to show, but you can choose particular domains for each function which produce comparable results.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       clip=true,
       width = 10cm, height= 8cm,
       xlabel = {$x$},
       ylabel = {$f(x)$},
%       ymin=-2, ymax=2
    ]
       \addplot[smooth] gnuplot[id=tanh]{tanh(x)};
       \foreach \data in {-3,-2,-1,0,1, 2, 3}{
          \addplot[only marks, black] coordinates {(\data, {tanh(\data)})};
        }
       \addplot[domain=-1.1:0.5,samples=25, smooth] gnuplot[id=poly]{(x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An alternative that avoids having to set the `domain` for each plot individually is to set `restrict y to domain=-2:2` for the `axis`.

Answer (score 2):

This uses just some terms in the Taylor expansion of `tanh(x)`.
(It's the blue line)

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       clip=true,
       width = 10cm, height= 8cm,
       xlabel = {$x$},
       ylabel = {$f(x)$},
       ymin=-2, ymax=2, xmin=-10, xmax=10]
       \addplot[domain=-10:10,smooth] gnuplot[id=tanh]{tanh(x)};
       \foreach \data in {-3,-2,-1,0,1, 2, 3}{
         \addplot[only marks, black] coordinates {(\data, {tanh(\data)})};
       }
       \addplot[domain=-1:1, samples=501, smooth] gnuplot[id=poly]{(x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x)}; % Nope!
       \addplot[blue,thick,domain=-1:1, samples=101, smooth]{x - (1.0/3) * x^3+2.0/15*x^5-17/315*x^7-62.0/2835*x^9};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]